# MassTransit StateMachine saga with IJobConsumer

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

Documentation is not exactly up to date, is it possible/how to configure web api with state machine saga so I can get all the goodies from that but instead of IConsumer I want to use IJobConsumer for the benefit of long living taking place on the other side of rabbitmq.
Currently I have api with job service going on, which publish messages to specified queues for the IConsumer but those are for short lived tasks and I couldn't get the cancellationToken working for them as well.

Comment: Not nearly enough information, you'd need a full repository reproducing the problem before anyone could even hazard a guess. You could also contact support if you have an agreement in place.